# Create SQLite database in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I have created Application of windows Phone 8.1 using Visual Studio 2015.
I have implement SQLite but got below error

```
"An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in SQLiteWp8.1.exe but was not handled in user code. 
Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you add the conditional compilation constant  USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671?redir=0

Comment: Did you add a reference to SQLite?

Comment: are you sure it is a correct library for windows phone 8.1? you can check nuget package manager to get the one which support windows phone 8.1